# How to identify changes name in dplyr() groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, lag

I am trying to figure out how to identify name changes within a group.

For example, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    df <- data.frame(
  state = rep(c("CA", "WI", "NY"), each = 3),
  year = rep(c(2000, 2001), each = 9),
  name = c("John", "Paul", "Sally",
           "Mary", "Fred", "Jane",
           "Linda", "Carl", "Jim",
           "Peter", "Paul", "Sally",
           "Mary", "Kate", "Jane",
           "Linda", "Carl", "Jim")
)

    > df
   state year  name
1     CA 2000  John
2     CA 2000  Paul
3     CA 2000 Sally
4     WI 2000  Mary
5     WI 2000  Fred
6     WI 2000  Jane
7     NY 2000 Linda
8     NY 2000  Carl
9     NY 2000   Jim
10    CA 2001 Peter
11    CA 2001  Paul
12    CA 2001 Sally
13    WI 2001  Mary
14    WI 2001  Kate
15    WI 2001  Jane
16    NY 2001 Linda
17    NY 2001  Carl
18    NY 2001   Jim
```

As you can see, "Peter" replaced "John" in 2001, and "Kate" replaced "Fred" in 2001.

So I want the output to look like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  state = rep(c("CA", "WI", "NY"), each = 3),
  year = rep(c(2000, 2001), each = 9),
  name = c("John", "Paul", "Sally",
           "Mary", "Fred", "Jane",
           "Linda", "Carl", "Jim",
           "Peter", "Paul", "Sally",
           "Mary", "Kate", "Jane",
           "Linda", "Carl", "Jim"),
  change = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
             1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)

   > df
   state year  name change
1     CA 2000  John     NA
2     CA 2000  Paul     NA
3     CA 2000 Sally     NA
4     WI 2000  Mary     NA
5     WI 2000  Fred     NA
6     WI 2000  Jane     NA
7     NY 2000 Linda     NA
8     NY 2000  Carl     NA
9     NY 2000   Jim     NA
10    CA 2001 Peter      1
11    CA 2001  Paul      0
12    CA 2001 Sally      0
13    WI 2001  Mary      0
14    WI 2001  Kate      1
15    WI 2001  Jane      0
16    NY 2001 Linda      0
17    NY 2001  Carl      0
18    NY 2001   Jim      0
```

As you can see, Peter in 2001 and Kate in 2001 are both marked as "1" in the "change" column because they replaced "John" and "Fred" in 2000-CA and 2000-NY, respectively.

I've been looking at using some lag methods, but it seems to just look at the previous row, not by state, year groups:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(state, year) %>%
  mutate(change = lag(name, order_by = year))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @akrun I provided some more context. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: There does not seem to be more logic to your comment  "Peter" replaced "John" in 2001, and "Kate" replaced "Fred" in 2001"

Is the data sequential and hence need to check based on the sequence i.e check row 1 with row 9 to acertain the change?

lag() also take (n) number of index to lag

Comment: @Vinay I'm sorry for the confusion. I've edited the post to clarify. So John, Paul, and Sally are in one group in CA 2000, but in CA 2001, John is replaced by Peter. I want a column that indicates that Peter is the "new" person in the group.

Comment: @hy9fesh for the new data in the comment, what is the expected.  Your logic as I said earlier is kind of confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the expected output, maybe this helps - create a logical column based on the `duplicated` 'name' in the entire data, then grouped by 'year', `if` `all` values are FALSE (`!change`), then replace with `NA` or `else`   convert the logical to binary (`+`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    arrange(state, year, name) %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate(change = !duplicated(name)) %>% 
    group_by(year, .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(
      change = if(all(change)) NA_integer_ else +(change)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   arrange(rn) %>% 
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 4
   state  year name  change
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <int>
 1 CA     2000 John      NA
 2 CA     2000 Paul      NA
 3 CA     2000 Sally     NA
 4 WI     2000 Mary      NA
 5 WI     2000 Fred      NA
 6 WI     2000 Jane      NA
 7 NY     2000 Linda     NA
 8 NY     2000 Carl      NA
 9 NY     2000 Jim       NA
10 CA     2001 Peter      1
11 CA     2001 Paul       0
12 CA     2001 Sally      0
13 WI     2001 Mary       0
14 WI     2001 Kate       1
15 WI     2001 Jane       0
16 NY     2001 Linda      0
17 NY     2001 Carl       0
18 NY     2001 Jim        0
```

---

Using another data showed in the comments

```
df2 <- structure(list(state = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK",  
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
 "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), year = c(1997L,  
1998L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1995L, 1996L, 1998L, 1997L, 1998L, 
 1996L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L,  
1995L, 1996L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L), name = c("A", "A",  "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D",  "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA,  -25L))
df2 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    arrange(state, year, name) %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate(change = !duplicated(name)) %>% 
    group_by(year, .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(
      change = if(all(change)) NA_integer_ else +(change)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   arrange(rn) %>% 
   select(-rn) %>%
   as.data.frame
```

-output

```
 state year name change
1     AK 1997    A      0
2     AK 1998    A      0
3     AK 1995    A     NA
4     AK 1996    A      0
5     AK 1997    B      0
6     AK 1995    B     NA
7     AK 1996    B      0
8     AK 1998    B      0
9     AK 1997    C      0
10    AK 1998    C      0
11    AK 1996    C      0
12    AK 1995    C     NA
13    AK 1996    D      1
14    AK 1997    D      0
15    AK 1998    D      0
16    AK 1995    E     NA
17    AK 1996    E      0
18    AK 1997    E      0
19    AK 1998    E      0
20    AK 1995    F     NA
21    AK 1996    F      0
22    AK 1995    G     NA
23    AK 1996    G      0
24    AK 1997    G      0
25    AK 1998    G      0
```

Comment: I applied it to this dataset: ```structure(list(state = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), year = c(1997L, 
1998L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1995L, 1996L, 1998L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1996L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1995L, 1996L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L), name = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work...the only "new" one is D, 1996, but it's marking more than that row as "1" in the change column.

Comment: @hy9fesh I updated the post with your new data.  Please check if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

A **base R** approach that leaves out `NA`s

```
df2 <- split(df, df$year)

cbind(df, change=rep((!(df2$"2000"$name == df2$"2001"$name))*1, length(df2)))
   state year  name change
1     CA 2000  John      1
2     CA 2000  Paul      0
3     WI 2000 Sally      0
4     WI 2000  Mary      0
5     NY 2000  Fred      1
6     NY 2000  Jane      0
7     CA 2000 Linda      0
8     CA 2000  Carl      0
9     WI 2000   Jim      0
10    WI 2001 Peter      1
11    NY 2001  Paul      0
12    NY 2001 Sally      0
13    CA 2001  Mary      0
14    CA 2001  Kate      1
15    WI 2001  Jane      0
16    WI 2001 Linda      0
17    NY 2001  Carl      0
18    NY 2001   Jim      0
```